# VB.NET: Clearing a picturebox

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

None of the code that I have seen so far to clear a picturebox achieved what I needed. 
I wanted to clear a picturebox so that I can draw something new over a "blank" background.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    PictureBoxClear(Me.PictureBox1)

    m_i = m_i + 1
    Dim nPT As New Point(0, 0)
    Me.ImageList1.Draw(Me.PictureBox1.CreateGraphics, nPT, m_i)

End Sub
Public Sub PictureBoxClear(ByRef pb As PictureBox)

    pb.Image = Nothing

End Sub
```

Saying

```
 .Image = Nothing
```

seems to completely remove the image so that I can not really draw something over it afterwards. 
I just wanted to clear my picturebox so that it would then ready be get some drawing again.

Thank you!

Comment: By "blank", you mean transparent?

Comment: The PictureBox is not meant to be drawn on.  You should draw onto an image and then update the PictureBox in the Paint event.  See this:  http://www.bobpowell.net/picturebox.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing it with a brand new image:

```
pb.Image =  New Bitmap(pb.ClientSize.Width, pb.ClientSize.Height)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. When I then draw something onto it after, the picturebox stays blank.

Comment: Are you perchance holding a reference to the old value of `pb.Image`?

Comment: No, this is all the code that I am using:     Public Class Form1

    Private m_i As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        PictureBoxClear(Me.PictureBox1)

        m_i = m_i + 1
        Dim nPT As New Point(0, 0)
        Me.ImageList1.Draw(Me.PictureBox1.CreateGraphics, nPT, m_i)

    End Sub
    Public Sub PictureBoxClear(ByRef pb As PictureBox)



    End Sub
End Class